# How do I stop iTunes complaining about compatibility mode in Windows 7 even when it is already switched off?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, compatibility

Since the iTunes 9.0.2.25 update (or thereabouts) on Windows 7 (32-bit) build 7100 I get the following message every time I start iTunes:

> ### iTunes
>
> iTunes.exe has been set to run in compatibility
>   mode for an older version of Windows.
>   For best results, turn off
>   compatibility mode for iTunes before
>   you open it.

I have checked `C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe` and compatibility mode is disabled, and I get the message even if I run it directly from there.

How do I get rid of the message?

Comment: This is definitely not an answer, but if you wait a few months, this problem will be solved "naturally"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOUND THE ANSWER and works 100% ! Windows 7 64 bit

You can read about it here:
http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10397771#10397771

Or if you don't want to open that and take a look just do this:

Locate:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

in your regedit

and delete the itunes.exe entry.!

Answer (score 0):

You said the compatibility mode is turned off for the .exe itself, but is it turned off for the shortcut you're using to open iTunes? Right-click the shortcut and go to Properties to check.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specifically say I'd checked that in the question, but I have. Running the .exe directly would avoid it anyway. :)